# Publish NON-ADFS Website to Internet with Web Application Proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, windows-server-2012

i have a server on my internal network having one IIS application which i want to publish to the internet using a proxy. The server my IIS is running on is Windows Server 2012 R2. So i thought why not using Web Application Proxy, but this requires me to have ADFS running. But i dont use ADFS, neither my IIS application depend on AD at all, so how can i publish my iis app (only this app) on my internal server to the internet? Looks like its not possible with the Web application proxy if your iis app does not work with ADFS?

Answer (score 0):

ADFS is a requirement for Web Application Proxy, no matter your apps require it or not. Thus, it will not hurt to lower the specs of your ADFS server.

However, you can deploy your apps using pass-through on Web Application Proxy if you do not need to take benefits from ADFS.